# Why HTML form empty field auto check disabled when false is returned from JS function on click of submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, razor

If an HTML form contains an input text field and it is declared like this:

```
<input type="email" id="loginEmail" placeholder="Email address" required>
```

Then the if this field is empty and user clicks on submit button then an error appears that "Please fill out this field"(Stackoverflow wont let me upload images because my reputation is too low :( )

But if the click on submit button of this form is handled via Javascript or JQuery and if false is returned from the function, no notification appears and no checking happens.
How to resolve it? I want to handle the onClick event of submit button but still want this feature of checking empty fields. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <input type="email" id="loginEmail" placeholder="Email address" required >
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
    alert('haii');
    if(document.getElementById('loginEmail').value==''){
        alert('the field should not remain empty');
    }
     }, 3000);


</script>
```

I think the above code may help you.

Comment: I knew that already, but i wanted to trigger the HTML automatic form validation. But Thanks anyway...

Comment: @ Asad : You can do this by auto submit the form.

Comment: @ Asad: check mu updated post.

Comment: @ Asad : If you are aggred you should upvote this.

Comment: I would have, but my reputation won't allow me...